# GetDlgItemInt returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a dialog and a picture control inside of it. During OnInitDialog I try to obtain the text part of the picture control like this

```
CWnd *dialogHandle; // Handle of the dialog  
CWnd *itemHandle; // Handle of the picture control  
BOOL error;  
dialogHandle->GetDlgItemInt(itemHandle->GetDlgCtrlID(), &error, 0);
```

however GetDlgItemInt function set error to 0 which says there is an error

here is the resource line

```
CONTROL 65443, IDC_PICTURE, "Static", SS_BITMAP, 13, 13, 40, 40
```

I want this number 65443

Answer (score 1):

You want GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_ID); (or the MFC equivalent).

GetDlgItemInt() is simply an atoi() wrapper around GetDlgItemText(), which reads the label of the control, not its ID.

Comment: GWLP_ID corresponts to IDC_PICTURE
I feel like I am very close the answer thank you :)

Comment: I don't want the id of the control, 65443 is the id of the bitmap I intended to show in the static control. I want it. Hovewer GWLP_ID is the id of the control which is 65923

Answer (score 0):

[`GetDlgItemInt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7t43w0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is supposed to get a text out of control. The second parameter is referred to as 'translated' flag and not an 'error' flag. Is this realy the method you are looking for? I think you need something else.

Comment: yes I might be looking something else but I really don't have any idea, It works well for texts and I felt it might be working for integers :\ but it didn't so far